# Local Maximas in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics, signal-processing

In Matlab, by the function max ()， I can only get one single maximum element of a vector, even if there can be several local maximum elements. I was wondering how to get values of all local maximas in MATLAB.

Comment: finding local maxima and using the function max are completelly different things. Max gives you the maximum values, not the maxima.

Comment: Ander Biguri this is what i want to ask that how to find local maxima because I only know about the mentioned command and it gives us the 1 maximum value

Comment: But that is an optimization algorithms job. There is no "a way", depedns in your problem. Do you have an equation? just an array of values?

Comment: I have an array of values and want to find local maxima for those values.
What I have to do I have to find Local maximas and make my signal flat at all local maximas .
So I have set of array which contains values for my signal and want to calculate local maximas for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local maximums will always have this characteristic:

1) The prior point will always be less.
2) The following point will always be less.

So you could do something like this:

```
% Example input vector a
a = [0 1 2 1 2 3 2 1 0 1 2 1 5 2 1 4 1];

% Shift vectors so that prior point and next point lines up with
% current point. 
prior_points   = a(1:(length(a) - 2));
current_points = a(2:(length(a) - 1));
next_points    = a(3:length(a));

% Identify indices where slope is increasing from prior to current
% and decreasing from current to next.
prior_slope_positive = ((current_points  - prior_points)    > 0);
next_slope_negative  = ((next_points     - current_points)  <= 0);

% This will return indices of local maximas.  Note that the result
% is incremented by one since current_points was shifted once.
b = find(prior_slope_positive & next_slope_negative) + 1;
```

Note that this example does not include the first and last points as potential local maximas.

The local maximas in vector a are:
    Index    Value
    3        2
    6        3
    11       2
    13       5
    16       4

Therefore, at the conclusion vector b will be equal to:
[3 6 11 13 16]

Comment: thanks a lot Jonathon S let me try this then i will get back to u . Thanks

Comment: Jonathon what do u mean by (a) here becaue this code is giving me just increasing values of local maximas when i put my data but for my case i have local maximas on decreasing trends also so in this case i am only getting linear curve

Comment: Peter.  I updated my answer for clarity and included an example.  Vector a is what I am using as the input vector and vector b will contain a list of indices for the local maxima.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked perfect and one last thing this code is giving me location of local maximas but f I want to find values of local maximas because i need those also.

Comment: Just use the following:  `c = a(b);`  This will set `c` equal to the value of the maximas in `a`.  It basically indexes `a` with all of the indices stored in `b`.

Comment: I have got the link so i can consult that thanks a lot for ur help ..

Comment: Thanks a lot for update it worked great... It worked like a piece of cake thanks again for help